# Highlight row in LaTex

Tags: tables, highlighting

I would like to highlight the first row in a table, starting with "Date"

Here is a screenshot of the table in question:

[image: Table with no highlighted rows]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What kind of highlighting do you have in mind?

Comment: I was thinking of gray. I tried the following \rowcolor[lightgray]{0.8} somehow it didn't work.

Answer (score 19):

This requires the `xcolor` package, its `table` option and the `\rowcolor` command.

From my point of view, there are too many lines in this table, but... well, it's the OP's design...

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{l|}}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} Date & Time & Instruction & Design \tabularnewline
 & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
 & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
 & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example table with colored rows]

Comment: To avoid option conflicts in a Beamer document, I used `\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}`.

Comment: Its not working tabularx environment.